# change the value of the input element

Tags: jquery

the following code is costing me a lot of precious time, can anybody help me on this??

```
<div id="i">
    <input id="Text1" type="text" value="hello" onClick="hello();"/>
</div>

<script>
    function hello() {
        var x = $("#i").html();
        var y = $(x).val();
        alert(y);
    }
</script>
```

in the case above the word "hello" is alerted each and every time, what if i want to alert the user input???
i.e. how do i change the "value" attribute of the input field????
thanks a trillion

Comment: Why do you do `var x = $("#i").html();` ? Why not just `alert($('#Text1').val())` ? (works for me)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#Text1").click(
    function(){
        val = $(this).val(); // get the value of the input
        $(this).val('the new input value'); // set the value of the input
    }
);
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
function hello(){
    alert($("#Text1").val());//text that user has inputted
    $("#Text1").val('new text');//set new text for input element
}
```

Comment: @Lina: i've updated my answer. It seems to me that everything will work fine -> first line is alerted text that user has inputted and the second one is set the value of input element to 'new text'.

Comment: i added the following line to your code:
alert($("#i").html());
and i'm still getting "hello" as a value for the input element.

Comment: but if you even try $("#Text1").attr('value') you'll get the new value of input. Not sure, but i suppose the actual html code will always remains the same... Are you sure you're really need it(html), but not a value?

Comment: @Lina: This code as it is should do it. If it does not, you are doing something different.